# How do I insert two ID's into a SQL Server intersection table without displaying their details in a Windows Form Application? ( Visual C# )

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, lambda, many-to-many

I have two tables in my database: People and Tags.

Each person may have multiple tags and each tag may belong to multiple people (a many-to-many relationship). Therefore, I created an intersection table (consisting of a compound Primary Key that doubles as Foreign Keys referencing their tables, respectfully) that represents this many-to-many relationship by forming two one-to-many relationships.

I'm using an ADO.NET entity model (Objects). Here's the kicker. The Intersection table disappeared when I created the model. It is represented in the model as a many-to-many relationship (gone). So I figured out I could create another datasource that references the database. I placed the databound details of People and Tags in the Form and placed a DataGridView control in the Form as well. HERE IS MY CODE:::

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BindingIntersecxs
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'jalopyDataSet.Person_Tag_Int' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
         this.person_Tag_IntTableAdapter.Fill(this.jalopyDataSet.Person_Tag_Int);

         db.People
            .OrderBy(a => a.PersonID)            
            .Load();

         personBindingSource.DataSource = db.People.Local;

         db.Tags
            .OrderBy(a => a.TagID)
            .Load();

         tagBindingSource.DataSource = db.Tags.Local;

      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         try
         {
            person_Tag_IntTableAdapter.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(personIDTextBox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(tagIDComboBox.Text));
            this.person_Tag_IntTableAdapter.Fill(this.jalopyDataSet.Person_Tag_Int);
         }
         catch (FormatException)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Format Exception caught inside btn1_Click");
         }         
      }
   }
}
```

[Here's a screenshot of my Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX1tv.png)

I can get the ID fields to enter into the DataGridView but if I switch their 'Visible' properties to False, I get the FormatException that's thrown in button1_Click.

How do I get the Primary Keys inserted into the intersection table without displaying them in the form?

Comment: Did you mean, Your ID should be auto incremented for the details you enter in the windows form ? Like 1001 Donald, 1002 Micheal. This kind, doesn't need to show the Id in the windows form. Whenever you enter new record. Id will be automatically generated

Comment: No. I handle that in a different form. This is just a litmus test (if you will). I'm just trying to get the ID's into the table at the bottom of the form without actually displaying them in the form. Did you see the picture?( http://i.stack.imgur.com/VX1tv.png )

Comment: The ID columns are set to IDENTITY(1000, 1) in SQL Server ( similar to AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT=1000 in MySQL ). They increment automatically. I just want to get that info inserted into the intersection table without having to display them on the form.

Comment: Obviously you saw the picture. I just realized you wouldn't have had that info had you not seen the screenshot.

Comment: Oh, and the details are bound to their respective tables. If I were to save the information, nothing would be inserted into the intersection table.

Comment: I literally converted the Text in the respective ID ComboBox'es to integers and inserted them into the table using LINQ and DataSource (Database conn).

Comment: See the line in the try block of button1_Click:             person_Tag_IntTableAdapter.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(personIDTextBox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(tagIDComboBox.Text));

Comment: You can Hide the TextBox And Make the Button alone visible

Comment: I tried that and it threw the FormatException in button1_Click. By hiding the boxes you mean setting their Visible properties to False?

Comment: The main thing to understand here (I think) is that the intersection table disappeared when I created the ADO.NET Entity Model.

Comment: I was able to pull up a DataGridView but I ultimately cannot get the ID's to insert into the DataGridView without displaying them in the form.

Comment: In SQL it would be something like 
INSERT INTO Person_Tag_INT 
(TagID, PersonID) values 

[(SELECT PersonID
FROM People
Where PersonID = "personIDComboBox.Text",

SELECT TagID
FROM Tags
WHERE TagID = "tagIDComboBox.Text" )]

Except that's not real syntax and I don't want to display the information on the form.

Comment: In Datagrid, Dont display ID. Only display the things You want. Else Without displaying the Datagrid, Insert the Values.

Comment: So, where do I get the values for the respective ID columns that can be inserted into the DataGrid?

Comment: I can delete the DataGrid and the information is still saved into the database. The problem is that I can't find another way to reference the Primary Key of either table.

Comment: I don't want to change what's in the intersection table. I created it like that so that there is no ambiguity. I don't want to display ID's on the form whatsoever and I can't create data integrity without them.

Comment: http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/67786